# Modal Bootstrap blocks other JavaScript (carousel and navbar)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap. At the beginning I had just a navbar with a scroll down menu, and a carousel on my page.
I decided to add a modal on click of some pictures, but now, I can't click on my navbar or my carousel prev/next buttons.
I think there is something doing with Javascript. But I don't know how to do!

**Navbar code**

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-left">
        <%= link_to image_tag("logoseul.png", alt: "logo") %>
        </ul>
        <%= link_to "PYL *", root_path, id: "logo" %>

        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Gallery", root_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Private darkroom", current_user %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

**Carousel**

```
<div class="span5">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <%= link_to image_tag("pylslide1.jpg", alt: "takepicture", width: "600", height:"300") %>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <%= link_to image_tag("pylslide2.jpg", alt: "modifyit", width: "600", height:"300") %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel nav -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
      </div>    
    </div>
```

**Modal**

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        <%= image_tag feed_item.image.url,:size => "180x180" %>
    </a>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <aside>                         
                            <section>
                                <br \>
                                <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
                            </section>
                        </aside>
                        <aside class="center">
                            <section>
                                <%= image_tag feed_item.image.url%>
                                <span class="timestamp">
                                    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.

                                    <% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
                                    <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete,
                                    data: { confirm: "You sure?" }%>
                                    <% end %>
                                </span>
                            </section>
                        </aside>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**SOLVED**

Finally found a solution there: [Twitter Bootstrap modal blocks text input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795035/twitter-bootstrap-modal-blocks-text-input-field)
I added `style="display:none"` and now it works perfectly.

Comment: You mean you can't click on it when the modal comes up? If so, that's intentional behavior if the mask is set to show.

Comment: No,  when modal is not open, carousel is not working!

Comment: Are there any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: No! Maybe it's  not javascript i have just supposed that because these 3 elements use javascript.

Comment: Nobody can help me with that ?

Comment: I have edited with my final solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find solution there : Twitter Bootstrap modal blocks text input field you can add style="display:none" and now it should work perfectly