# Twitter Bootstrap 3 modal blocking input fields after scrolling botttom?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I have searched for this issue. I followed the answers in this question

[Twitter Bootstrap modal blocks text input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795035/twitter-bootstrap-modal-blocks-text-input-field)

However my issue is still there.

here is my modal html

```
<div class="modal fade" style="display:none;" id="stockPerLocationModal" data-backdrop="static" ng-app="productInventory" ng-controller="ProductInventoryCtrl">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Stock per location</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <table class=" table responsive shopex-table table-hover no-margin">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Outlet Name</th>
                                    <th>Stock</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="val in outlets">
                                    <td class="vcenter" ng-model="val.Name">
                                        {{val.Name}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{val.Stock}}" ng-model="val.Stock">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-red" id="btnSaveProductInventory" ng-click="updateProductInventory()">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am showing this modal on a button click.

here is the JS :

```
 function showStockPerLocationModal() {
      //  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
        $('#stockPerLocationModal').modal('show');   
    }
```

I added the event as described in the answer :

```
 $('#stockPerLocationModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
           $(document).off('focusin.modal');
        });
```

however when the modal is open, I can not enter text in my input fields.

If i scroll the window to the top. It will work.

so I added this line of code before opening the modal in this function showStockPerLocationModal.

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
```

any reason why twitter bootstrap 3 modal block input fields after the page is scrolled ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use this fiddle in order to reproduce your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/540bcohh/

Comment: it is working there. Since there is no scroll to the bottom happened.

Comment: Since you're using Angular, just use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

Check your z-index and positioning. Make sure the z-index on your modal window is higher than any elements toward the bottom of the page. Apply position:relative to your modal if needed