# Cannot type (or even focus) in input type="text" while bootstrap modal is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jquery code that creates a dropdown menu and places it exactly where the user right-clicked. Everything works fine except one thing: I cannot type inside an input field.

The generated dropdown looks as follows:

```
<ul role="menu" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 751px; top: 294px; z-index: 999999;">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="filter"></li>
    <li style="height:200px;" class="scroll-container-y">
        <ul class="list-unstyled gutter-left-small">
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In my idea, the input will be used to filter the Sublinks.

What I've tried (with no results):

- Change z-index
- Force $('input').focus()
- Force $('input').get(0).focus()
- Playing around with CSS to check if it was just white text over white background
- Reviewed code to see if some other jQuery was interfering

Hope you guys can help.

EDIT (working example):
It appears that this is a Bootstrap problem: as you can see from this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2gkjb0h8/3/ the input can be entered UNTIL the bootstrap modal is opened. Still no clue on how to solve this.

EDIT 2:
Here's an image of what I want to achieve http://prnt.sc/bxbucf
In the modal, there will be a table with selectable TDs; once selected, the user can right click to open a context menu with a list of teachers (each of them is a link). This works already, the input is there to allow filtering all the possible names.

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Comment: Remove `display: none`

Comment: Nearly impossible without being able to reproduce the error. Works for me [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hbwm9bmq/)

Comment: What do you mean by "...I cannot type inside..."? Is it that the list closes as soon as you click on the input field or something else?

Comment: If you have other input elements on the page, the `$(input)` selector may be the problem as it may be not be specific enough. Try giving the input element an `id` and access it with `$('#idname')`

Comment: @Bart I wish I could...
@Pugazh I tried setting `display: block !important` but it didn't solve anything

Comment: @Bart I use a dynamic selector based on `mousedown(function(event))`, then `$(event.target).focus()`... I doubt that's the problem

Comment: A "working example" means an example that demonstrates your issue.  ie a working example of the non-working situation.  I'm sure you already have, but read this [mcve] with emphasis on verifiable.

Comment: @FDavidov no, the list doesn't close... everything else seems ok; I tried to force a .focus() because I can correctly select the element, but still nothing

Comment: @freedomn-m the project is huge, I'm trying to reproduce the error.

Comment: In doing so, you may find your issue :)  good luck

Comment: @freedomn-m I edited with a working example of the error

Comment: @Bart I edited with a working example of the error

Comment: I checked your example and it puzzles me... You are opening a **MODAL** and, while still open, trying to type into an element that is not part of the **MODAL**... is this supposed to work at all? I mean, MODAL means MODAL, right?

Comment: @FDavidov Accurate, but I need the user to interact with a selection of elements displayed in the modal.
EXAMPLE: select the items you want from a table, right-click and pick an action from the list

Comment: I'm sorry but don't quite understand what you are looking for.

Comment: @FDavidov I just want to be able to type inside an input field.
from the [screenshot](http://prnt.sc/bxbucf) you can see a MODAL, a SELECTION, the CONTEXT MENU with the INPUT bordered in black. I cannot type in there

Comment: The link to the screenshot does not work. You can add a picture to your original question.

Comment: "*but I need the user to interact with a selection of elements displayed in the modal*" then you need to move the input (or the `ul` menu) into the modal.  You'll need to some js to hook into the modal show (or show the modal via js) if you need the "menu" also outside the modal - or just add extra html inside.

Comment: @freedomn-m your last idea seemed good, so I gave it a try... but it didn't work. By chance, there was something that DID WORK: I opened another modal from that ul (so now we have two modals opened), then I closed it (back to one). Opened the UL again, and now I was able to type into it. It's driving me nuts

Answer (score 32):

It appears that this answer would resolve your problem.

[Twitter Bootstrap modal blocks text input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795035/twitter-bootstrap-modal-blocks-text-input-field)

The author recommends against a modal for this scenario (and I agree).

> It sounds like a modal isn't the right solution to your problem here.
>
> A modal dialog by definition shouldn't allow the user to interact with anything below it.

However, he does provide a workaround:

**Bootstrap 2**

```
$('#myModal1').on('shown', function() {
    $(document).off('focusin.modal');
});
```

You can see this in action on an updated jsfiddle of your original solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/2gkjb0h8/4/

**Bootstrap 3**

It should also be noted that the event names changed in Bootstrap 3:

```
$('#myModal1').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $(document).off('focusin.modal');
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea how I missed that. I agree with the fact that a modal should not allow interaction with other elements, but looking at my EDIT 2 (the image) would you say this is my case? In my opinion it's not applicable since it's a context menu based on the content of the modal. EDIT: this enables interaction with ANY other element, could I just limit this to the input field?

Comment: I would have considered a popover or something similar if I were starting this from scratch. But choosing the right tool for the job is really your judgment call. If a modified modal works for you, great. I just think it's worth noting in the answer that modals purposely steal the focus from the background UI elements.

Comment: Just noticed your EDIT: "this enables interaction with ANY other element, could I just limit this to the input field?"

While I'm sure this is definitely possible, I believe improving the code further would be beyond the scope of your original question. I think this is a separate additional challenge, and I simply don't know enough about the rest of your page/project to be able to make a good recommendation.

Comment: What would be solution while using in ReactJs and https://reactstrap.github.io/

Answer (score 22):

```
<div id="myModal1" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

tabindex is used to define whether elements should be focusable or not within a page. You have used tabindex attribute so that focus is on modal and you can't able to enter text on text box. Just remove tabindex you can able to enter text.

```
<div id="myModal1" class="modal hide" role="dialog">
```

[Click here to check on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gkjb0h8/21/)

Comment: It does work in the fiddle, but for some reason it doesn't on my website. I wish it did... Could it be that the content is js-generated? I even tried using a positive tabindex to see if I could solve it, but no luck

Comment: Thanx, My problem was resolved by this answer. Can you explain why tabindex="-1" ? .

Comment: In my case, we had the problem while opening a modal having some text inputs from another modal having the tabindex="-1". Removing it helped to solve our issue. TY

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the element is in `DOM` when you are trying to focus on it.

You can call this once this component is visible after right click. Also use assign an `id` to this input element.

```
$('body').find('#idOfInput').focus();
```

Comment: Yes, the element is already in DOM at the moment of focusing. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can try usind data-target to focus the input

```css
.btn-group {
    z-index: 1051;
}

ul[role="menu"]{
  position: absolute; 
  left: 50px; 
  top: 400px;
  z-index: 999999;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
<div class="container">

        <h3>Inputting proble</h3>

        <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
        <div>
            <a href="#myModal1" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#text"  class="test" >Launch Modal</a>
            <p>
            Now you are able to enter text in the input field below. Once tested, open the modal.
            </p>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="myModal1" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3>Modal</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Now you will not be able to enter text in the input</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <ul role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><input id="text" type="text" name="filter"  ></li>
    <li style="height:200px;" class="scroll-container-y">
        <ul class="list-unstyled gutter-left-small">
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using bootstrap modal version `4.3.1`. The prescribed solution to remove the focus out of the open modal was not working for me.So, I ended up removing the modal entirely from my code. And used combination of css attributes `position` ,`z-index` and `display` to achieve the same look as that of a modal dialog.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
   .rootDivKlass {
        position: relative;
        width: 800px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: #A64831;
    }

    .backGroundDivKlass {
        background-color: #BEB2AF;
        height:400px;
        width:500px;
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .myModalLikeDivKlass {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        display: block;
        width: 290px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 100px;
        background-color: white;    
    }
    .inputDivKlass {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 550px;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
    </style> 
</head>

<body>
   <div class="rootDivKlass">
        <div id="modalBackgroundDiv" class="backGroundDivKlass">        
        </div>
        <div class="myModalLikeDivKlass">
            <center><font color="blue">Put your modal content here</center>
        </div>
        <div class="inputDivKlass">
           <input type="text"/>
        </div>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

Correct! Tabindex is used to define whether elements should be focusable or not within a page. You have used tabindex attribute so that focus is on modal and you can't able to enter text on text box. Just remove tabindex you can able to enter text.