# Textarea doesn't get focus when bootstrap modal is opened

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1921/

I can't type in textarea, when the modal is opened.

Textarea is not in modal and has absolute positioning with large z-index.

```
<textarea style='position:absolute;z-index:200000'></textarea>
```

Can anyone override this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap modal blocks text input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795035/twitter-bootstrap-modal-blocks-text-input-field)

Comment: It looks like Boostrap has some `enforceFocus` code blocking you. See my answer below.

Comment: There is no suitable answer in the dublicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks this [line of code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v2.3.1/js/bootstrap-modal.js#L73) is the problem where Bootstrap enforces focus each time you show the modal. So let's remove the event each time:

```
$('#myModal1').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $(document).off('focusin.modal');
})
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1924/).

Comment: I added this piece of code in DOMready in my code, it doesn't fix.
However in my Fiddle it worked, yes

Comment: Could you help?

Comment: Alright, let me update my answer to address the enforce focus directly...

Comment: Hold on, that's not doing the trick. Trying another approach. Maybe we can kill that event altogether...

Comment: Your code works in Fiddle, but for my code it gives nothing)

Comment: Ok see updated answer/fiddle once more. Make sure the selector is right for your modal `#myModal1`. We'll just kill that handler.

Comment: What did you change? I'm using $('.modal') for all modals

Comment: Good job! Thanks!

Comment: Woohoo! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Remove `tabindex="-1"` from `<div id="myModal1" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">` and will work. Don't understand why `tabindex` is creating this problem.

Comment: If I delete tabindex, would it cause problems?

Comment: `tabindex` is use to set focus order when you press tab through keyboard.  you can find more details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911355/whats-the-tabindex-1-in-bootstrap-for

Comment: So, I shoudn't delete it

Comment: documentation says `tabindex="-1"` is used to make modal disappear when user press `esc` key, so its up to you.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is using Bootstrap Vue and seeing this same issue:

Bootstrap Vue provides a b-modal property named "ignore-enforce-focus-selector". You can use this property to provide a selector (including a comma-separated selector list) that specifies elements that can be focused even while the modal is visible. In my case, I had a number of textarea elements that needed to be focusable while the modal was visible. Setting "ignore-enforce-focus-selector" to "textarea" made it possible to edit these textareas while the modal was visible.

See https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#keyboard-navigation

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea style='position:absolute;z-index:200000' autofocus></textarea>
```

Comment: Did you check it in my Fiddle? Your answer has no sense and doesn't work.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Its because I posted answer from mobile app, screen size is limited. Will keep in mind in future.

Comment: @SonyaSeyrios this answer helped you ?