# Cannot type in Blockly workspace in Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, blockly

I'm having a problem with a Blockly workspace inside a Bootstrap modal.

Everything seems to work fine, but I cannot type in the inputs that I drag into the workspace.

Here's what the dialog looks like:

[image]

I cannot type in the highlighted block, to the right of the equal sign.

I had a problem previously where the workspace would not show if rendered inside a collapsed `div`. I fixed this by adding an event which fires when *Step Formulas* is clicked and execute the following code:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

I validated that if I place the `div` in which the workspace is injected into the main layout's HTML, it works fine. I can type.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to manipulate the DOM and restructure it.

Those two divs are generated in the root of the DOM (body level). Moving them as child of the modal solved the focus issue.

```
$('.blocklyWidgetDiv').prependTo('.modal');
$('.blocklyTooltipDiv').prependTo('.modal');
```

Answer (score 0):

I too stumbled upon this issue a while ago, after quite a bit of searching found the reason and workaround to handle the issue.

The problem occurs because, one of the event listener set by bootstrap instantly sets focus to the bootstrap modal if focus is given to an element that isn't inside it. And unfortunately blockly doesn't create that input field inside the parent modal div (try to inspect the white textfield in browser, you will see it).

There are multiple workarounds for this, but the one which IMO is simplest and worked great for me is to use `tabindex` attribute in HTML.

Just add `tabindex="-1"` to the html element having bootstrap's `modal` class. Giving a negative value to `tabindex` removes the element from tab order, which indirectly solves our issue.

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1">
    <--other stuff + blockly here-->
</div>
```

Other workarounds can be found on these links: [link1](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/374) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795035/twitter-bootstrap-modal-blocks-text-input-field)