# I can't write in a Bootstrap Modal in Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on a project with Angular and I need a modal to open when clicking a button.
So far so good, the problem is that once the modal is open I can't edit any text input fields. This happens when I open the modal from a drawer I made in Bootstrap, if I open it from a normal button it works correctly and I can edit the inputs.

I've tried few things of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795035/twitter-bootstrap-modal-blocks-text-input-field) but nothing worked for me.

Here you have my code.

**DRAWER - SIDENAV**

```
<!-- BUTTON THAT CALLS THE DRAWER -->
<div class="toolbar" role="banner">
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#myDrawer" aria-controls="myDrawer">
        <fa-icon id="btnMenu" [icon]="faBars" size="2x"></fa-icon>
    </button>
    <h1>Gestión de proyectos</h1>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>

<!-- WITH THIS BUTTON IT WORKS PERFECT -->
<button (click)="openModal(anadirCliente)" style="margin: 75px 15px">CLIENTE</button>

<!-- DRAWER -->
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="myDrawer" aria-labelledby="myDrawerLabel">
    <div class="offcanvas-header">
        <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="myDrawerLabel">MENÚ</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Cerrar"></button>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <div id="accordion">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true"
                            aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            Cliente
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="float:right"
                            (click)="openModal(anadirCliente)"><fa-icon [icon]="faPlus" size="xl"></fa-icon>
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**MODAL**

```
<ng-template #anadirCliente let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Añadir Cliente</h4>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" aria-label="close" (click)="modal.dismiss()">X</button>
    </div>
    <form [formGroup]="formCliente" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitCliente()">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <label>Nombre:</label>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="rounded" formControlName="nombre" />
            <br>
            <label>Apodo:</label>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="apodo" id="apodo" class="rounded" formControlName="apodo" />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="modal.close()">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</ng-template>
<div *ngIf="errorMessageCliente" class="alert alert-danger">
    {{ errorMessageCliente }}
</div>
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formCliente = this.formBuilder.group({
      nombre: '',
      apodo: '',
    });
  }

  openModal(param: any) {
    this.modal.open(param, { centered: true });
  }
```

Comment: That drawer has some backdrop? If yes, you should check the z-index of it, maybe the modal below that backdrop.

Comment: I didn't specify any backdrop param, so I think it's the default value. I've already tried with z-index=999

Comment: Fair point of @Zsolt. Have you tried using DevTools (F12) - "Select element" command - and just try to select the textbox. You should be able to see what's in the way